# Changing validation pattern at run-time in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a template driven form with a pattern validation that works fine:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="model.defaultVal" 
       name="defaultVal" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]*" />
<div *ngIf="defaultVal.touched || !defaultVal.pristine">
     <label *ngIf="defaultVal.control.hasError('pattern')">
           Invalid value
     </label>
</div>
```

But what I need is to change the pattern at run-time. Is this possible using template driven forms?

Comment: Are you using Reactive forms?

Comment: Yes, but I prefer not to change it to reactive as the program is already in production

Comment: when you say runtime at what moment do you want to change it?and what is the basis of changing it

Comment: I think you can insert another input with pattern whats you need and use ngIf to display input whats you need.

Comment: I would go with a custom directive - https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives

Comment: @ashok the pattern depends on the value of another variable on screen. If this variable changes, the validation pattern should change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the pattern directive like any other directive. A little example here. You can change the pattern or the given value.

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="pattern" />

<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="defaultVal" 
      #test="ngModel" [pattern]="pattern" />

<div *ngIf="test.touched || !test.pristine">
  <label *ngIf="test.control.hasError('pattern')">
    Invalid value
  </label>
</div>
```

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  defaultVal = 'Angular';
  pattern = '[a-zA-Z]*';
}
```

Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mnvcnx